# scraping multiple pages with multiple pages of data in each

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So i am scraping one one page using 4 different individual "projects" ..... here are two of them as examples.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from botg.items import BotgItem


URL = "http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/born-of-the-gods?PageNumber=%d"

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "tcg"
allowed_domains = ["tcgplayer.com"]
start_urls = [URL % 1]

def __init__(self):
    self.page_number = 1

def parse(self, response):
    print self.page_number
    print "--------------------BREAK-------------------------"

    sel = Selector(response)
    titles = sel.xpath("//div[@class='magicCard']")
    if not titles:
        raise CloseSpider('No more pages')

    for title in titles:
        item = BotgItem()
        item["cardname"] = title.xpath(".//li[@class='cardName']/a/text()").extract()[0]

        vendor = title.xpath(".//tr[@class='vendor ']")
        item["price"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='price']/text())").extract()
        item["quantity"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='quantity']/text())").extract()
        item["shipping"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='shippingAmount']/text())").extract()
        item["condition"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='condition']/a/text())").extract()
        item["vendors"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='seller']/a/text())").extract()
        yield item

    self.page_number += 1
    yield Request(URL % self.page_number)
```

there is one ... and the other is :

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from tcgplayer1.items import Tcgplayer1Item


URL = "http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/journey-into-nyx?pageNumber=%d"

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "tcg"
allowed_domains = ["tcgplayer.com"]
start_urls = [URL % 1]

def __init__(self):
    self.page_number = 1

def parse(self, response):
    print self.page_number
    print "----------"

    sel = Selector(response)
    titles = sel.xpath("//div[@class='magicCard']")
    if not titles:
        raise CloseSpider('No more pages')

    for title in titles:
        item = Tcgplayer1Item()
        item["cardname"] = title.xpath(".//li[@class='cardName']/a/text()").extract()[0]

        vendor = title.xpath(".//tr[@class='vendor ']")
        item["price"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='price']/text())").extract()
        item["quantity"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='quantity']/text())").extract()
        item["shipping"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='shippingAmount']/text())").extract()
        item["condition"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='condition']/a/text())").extract()
        item["vendors"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[@class='seller']/a/text())").extract()
        yield item

    self.page_number += 1
    yield Request(URL % self.page_number)
```

I would like to consolidate all this into one project that can scrape 4 pages and for each go through ~8 pages of data.  I think that this will require one "master" items file, but i cant seem to make the crawler go through more than one page and its data.

Comment: Have you solved it by now?